# How to get the parameter to work inside a event function

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I want to unbind(off) the events I wrapped the code inside a function but as I need to see which key is pressed I need to get the event of the event(not sure how this is called.

// normal example

```
$('body').on('keydown',function( event ){
    if(event.keyCode == 37){
        // do something
    }
});
```

// my example

```
function keyDownHandler() {
     if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        // does not work
    }    
 }

$('body').on('keydown', keyDownHandler);
```

Comment: `function keyDownHandler() ` to `function keyDownHandler(event) `

Comment: In the first example you defined a function with an `event` parameter, in second example you omitted the `event` parameter. Why? The difference  seems pretty obvious to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the event object, you can get it as callback function argument

```
function keyDownHandler(event) {
    // set it here ----^^^^^^---
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {
        // works now
    }
}

$('body').on('keydown', keyDownHandler);
```

Comment: @user759235 :  at least you need to check ur console.... there will be `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //1st way
    $('body').on('keydown', function(event){
        keyDownHandler(event);
    });

    //2nd way ,same as first but shorter use it for send event only
    $('body').on('keydown', keyDownHandler);

    //3rd way ,this way to send more data
    $('body').on('keydown', {example:'hello world'},keyDownHandler2);
});

function keyDownHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}

function keyDownHandler2(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    console.log(event.data.example);
}
```

Comment: Personally I find less code easier, hence I'd argue `$('body').on('keydown', keyDownHandler);` is the easiest way. But "easiest" is subjective anyway....